# Rearranging of contacts in chat application based on recent activity

Tags: android

I have built a chat application in android which is voice based. I am arranging my contact list alphabetically at present.

I want my application's contact list to be rearranged every time it receives a new voice message i.e  I want the contact name on the top which receives the voice message lately. (Same as that of WhatsApp chat list).

Please suggest me the component or method I need to implement in my application to get it done. Will share my piece of code if needed. Please Help

Thank you

Comment: you can take timestamp in your database and than list it in ascending or descending order

Comment: Any sample link or code to go with ?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new attribute to your database that holds the timestamp of the last activity by users. Each time a message is received, sort your list according to the timestamp retrieved from your database.

Answer (score 0):

watsapp store contact and  recent activity in their own local sqlite db.

so create you own sqlite db to track user activities